# How do I override the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler RememberNonce Method

Tags: openid-connect

I have an issue that seems well documented using Office 365 authentication where the cookie becomes too large for the headers as multiple nonce messages are stored.

I have found the following code but I can't get it to fire on authentication so can someone help with what I am missing:

```cs
public class SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler
{
    public SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler(ILogger logger)
        : base(logger) { }

    protected override void RememberNonce(OpenIdConnectMessage message, string nonce)
    {
        var oldNonces = Request.Cookies.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.StartsWith(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix + "nonce"));
        if (oldNonces.Any())
        {
            CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = Request.IsSecure
            };
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> oldNonce in oldNonces)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(oldNonce.Key, cookieOptions);
            }
        }
        base.RememberNonce(message, nonce);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wondering the same thing...

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that inherits from OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware class that returns the handler in the CreateHandler method.

```cs
public class SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware : OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions options) : base(next, app, options)
    {
        _logger = app.CreateLogger<SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware>();
    }

    protected override AuthenticationHandler<OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> CreateHandler()
    {
        return new SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler(_logger);
    }
}
```

Then add the middleware into the OWIN runtime.

For example:

```cs
public static IAppBuilder UseSawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions openIdConnectOptions)
{
    if (app == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("app");
    }

    if (openIdConnectOptions == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("openIdConnectOptions");
    }

    return app.Use(typeof(SawtoothOpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware), app, openIdConnectOptions);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, in my case, the problem was different, but with the same solution base based on specializing the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler to be able to add a required header forced to authenticate with Oracle Access Manager (OAM) when redeeming the authorization code in the TokenEndpoint. The method I replaced in my case was "RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync".
I copied all the source code code from the original Katana method (https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana) and added my header to the requestMessage that is built inside the method. 
I found no other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is rare that Oracle Access Manager (OAM) does not follow the library standard available for the .NET Framework 4.8. Requiring a particular header, which is outside the norm for the OIDC flow is not good practice.
Likewise, to get the standard configuration of the OpenID access point from OAM ("/.well-known/openid-configuration"), it also required a special call with HttpClient passing the same header.
**My Handle override for RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync to add a special header**
[Katana Source Code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana)

```csharp
protected override async Task<OpenIdConnectMessage> RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
{
    //return base.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(tokenEndpointRequest);
    var _configuration = Options?.Configuration;
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, _configuration.TokenEndpoint);
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("MY_HEADER_KEY"
        , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myheaderkey"]);
    requestMessage.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenEndpointRequest.Parameters);

    var responseMessage = await Backchannel.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    var contentMediaType = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType != null ? responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType : null;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentMediaType))
    {
        _logger.WriteVerbose(string.Format("Unexpected token response format. Status Code: {0}. Content-Type header is missing.", (int)responseMessage.StatusCode));
    }
    else if (!string.Equals(contentMediaType, "application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        _logger.WriteVerbose(string.Format("Unexpected token response format. Status Code: {0}. Content-Type {1}.", (int)responseMessage.StatusCode, responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType));
    }

    // Error handling:
    // 1. If the response body can't be parsed as json, throws.
    // 2. If the response's status code is not in 2XX range, throw OpenIdConnectProtocolException. If the body is correct parsed,
    //    pass the error information from body to the exception.
    OpenIdConnectMessage message;
    try
    {
        var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        message = new OpenIdConnectMessage(responseContent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new OpenIdConnectProtocolException(string.Format("Failed to parse token response body as JSON. Status Code: {0}. Content-Type: {1}", (int)responseMessage.StatusCode, responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType), ex);
    }

    if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        throw CreateOpenIdConnectProtocolException(message);
    }

    return message;
}

private OpenIdConnectProtocolException CreateOpenIdConnectProtocolException(OpenIdConnectMessage message)
{
    var description = message.ErrorDescription ?? "error_description is null";
    var errorUri = message.ErrorUri ?? "error_uri is null";

    var errorMessage = string.Format(
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        //Resources.Exception_OpenIdConnectMessageError,
        "OpenIdConnectMessage.Error was not null, indicating an error. Error: '{0}'. Error_Description (may be empty): '{1}'. Error_Uri (may be empty): '{2}'.",
        message.Error,
    description,
        errorUri);

    _logger.WriteError(errorMessage);

    var ex = new OpenIdConnectProtocolException(errorMessage);
    ex.Data["error"] = message.Error;
    ex.Data["error_description"] = description;
    ex.Data["error_uri"] = errorUri;
    return ex;
}
```

**Get OIDC standard configuration**

```csharp
private static readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
private static OpenIdConnectConfiguration GetMyCustomOIDCConfiguration()
{
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("MY_HEADER_KEY"
        , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myheaderkey"]);
    OpenIdConnectConfiguration config = OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever
        .GetAsync($"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myauthoritykey"]}" +
            $"/.well-known/openid-configuration"
            , _client, CancellationToken.None)
        .Result;

    return config;
}
```